# Async loop didn't wait

Tags: node.js, arrays, asynchronous

I am using node-async-loop for asyncronous programming

```
var array = ['item0', 'item1', 'item2'];
asyncLoop(array, function (item, next)
{
    do.some.action(item, function (err)
    {
        if (err)
        {
            next(err);
            return;
        }
 
        next();
    });
}, function (err)
{
    if (err)
    {
        console.error('Error: ' + err.message);
        return;
    }
 
    console.log('Finished!');
});
```

Like this I am using three async loops one under one.
I want to send the response only after the third inner loop ends. How can I do so?.
Here is the link for node-async-loop (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-async-loop)

here is my code which i writing but whnever i want to response when the last loop completes it say can set header after send to cliend.
also in console log i am getting data every time when data coming from query.

```
const id = req.params.id;
    finalData = [];
    tb_user.findOne({ where: { id: id } }).then((userRiverSys, err) => {
        if (userRiverSys) {
            // console.log(userRiverSys.regionJson)
            asyncLoop(userRiverSys.regionJson, function (item, next) {
                // console.log("item", item);
                tb_riverSystems.findAll(
                    {
                        where: { regionId: item.id }
                    }).then((findriverSys, err) => {
                        if (err) {
                            next(err);
                            return;
                        }
                        // console.log("findriverSys", findriverSys);
                        if (findriverSys) {
                            asyncLoop(findriverSys, function (item1, next1) {
                                if (err) {
                                    next(err);
                                    return;
                                }
                                // console.log("item1", item1.dataValues);
                                tb_facilities.findAll(
                                    {
                                        where: { riverSystemId: item1.dataValues.id }
                                    }).then((findFacilities) => {
                                        if (findFacilities) {
                                            // console.log("findFacilities", findFacilities[0].dataValues.name);
                                            asyncLoop(findFacilities, function (item2, next2) {
                                                if (err) {
                                                    next(err);
                                                    return;
                                                }
                                                tb_userAccess.findAll(
                                                    {
                                                        where: { facilityId: item2.dataValues.id }
                                                    }).then((userAccessFacilities, err) => {
                                                        // console.log("userAccessFacilities", userAccessFacilities[0].dataValues);
                                                        // var i = 0;
                                                        asyncLoop(userAccessFacilities, function (item3, next3) {
                                                            finalData.push({
                                                                UserId: item3.userid,
                                                                facilityId: item3.facilityId,
                                                            })

                                                            next3();
                                                        },
                                                            function (err) {
                                                                if (err) {
                                                                    console.error('Error: ' + err.message);
                                                                    return;
                                                                }
                                                                // i++;
                                                                // console.log('Finished!!!!');
                                                                // if (userAccessFacilities.length === i) {
                                                                //  console.log("finalData", i);
                                                                //  // res.json({"status":"true", "message":"update OrgChallenge"})
                                                                //    }
                                                            })
                                                            return  res.json({"status":"true", "message":"update OrgChallenge"})
                                                        
                                                            // console.log("finalData", finalData);

                                                    })
                                                next2();
                                            }, function (err) {
                                                if (err) {
                                                    console.error('Error: ' + err.message);
                                                    return;
                                                }
                                                console.log('Finished!!!');
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                next1();
                            }, function (err) {
                                if (err) {
                                    console.error('Error: ' + err.message);
                                    return;
                                }
                                console.log('Finished!!');
                            });
                        }
                    });
                next();
            }, function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error('Error: ' + err.message);
                    return;
                }
                console.log('Finished!');
            });

        } else {
            console.log("err3", err)
        }
    })
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you want to use this package? This can be done easily natively without having to rely on an extra package.

Comment: Way easier and simpler to code this with promises without using any external package.

Comment: i have used this packge  before where i send message only but this time need to send data in qurery

Comment: @jfriend00 can you me some example how can i proceed

Comment: @Harpritsingh - I provided an example in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you promisify your asynchronous action (so it returns a promise), then you can just use a regular `for` loop and `async/await` and there is no need for a 3rd party library to sequence your asynchronous loop.  This is modern Javascript:

```
const { promisify } = require('util');
do.some.actionP = promisify(do.some.action);

async function someFunction() {
    const array = ['item0', 'item1', 'item2'];
    for (let item of array) {
        let result = await do.some.actionP(item);
        // do something with result here
    }
    return someFinalResult;
}

someFunction().then(result => {
   console.log(result);
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err);
});
```

FYI, in real code, many (or even most) asynchronous operations now offer promisified versions of their API already so usually you don't even need to do the promisify step any more.  For example, pretty much all databases already offer a promise interface that you can just use directly.

Comment: but i didn't work with simple for in loop becoz it breaks if data is 1000 user or more so i use this package

Comment: @Harpritsingh - If `do.some.action()` calls its callback only when it is done, then this loop will work just fine no matter how many items you have because the loop runs the items one at a time.  It doesn't run the second one until the first one is done.  This will work fine with millions of items.  Your previous attempt at a loop  like this did not have promises and `await` like I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

```
const loop = async (arr, results = []) => {
  const item = arr.shift()
  if (!item) {
    console.log("DONE");
    return results;
  }

  // as async function
  await new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(results.push(`asynced-${item}`))
  })

  return loop(arr, results);
}

(async () => {
  const result = await loop(["item0", "item1", "item2"])
  console.log(result);
})();
```

I'd be happy if I can help you.
but this script uses a recursive function instead of `node-async-loop`.
so this might not be suitable for you.

Comment: this will not work means how this code is working i didn't understand